# How to calculate population fitness using PyGAD?

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I'd like to use PyGAD to solve job assignment problem and hope to get the result not only one chromosome but whole population. Such as [[1,1,0,0][0,0,1,1]] represent 4 slots,and 1 in first chromosome mean one guy assigned to those slots,another two slots assign to another guy according to second chromosome.

Follow the tutorial on the PyGAD website (https://pygad.readthedocs.io),am I doing right use `initial_population` to generate population？Is it right to use `cal_pop_fitness()` function ? I made some tries and still have no idea.

```
import pygad
import numpy

sol_per_pop = 2 
num_genes = 4 
pop_size = (sol_per_pop,num_genes) 

new_population = numpy.random.randint(low=0,high=2,size=pop_size) 

num_generations = 100
num_parents_mating = 2

def fitness_func(solution,solution_idx):
    fitness = ga_instance.cal_pop_fitness(new_population)
    #do something
    

ga_instance = pygad.GA(initial_population = new_population,
                       num_generations=num_generations,
                       num_parents_mating=num_parents_mating,
                       sol_per_pop=sol_per_pop,
                       num_genes=num_genes,
                       mutation_type=None,
                       fitness_func=fitness_func)
                       
ga_instance.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

I have some notes:

1. `cal_pop_fitness()` is not a function. It is a method in the `pygad.GA` class.
2. The `cal_pop_fitness()` method does not accept any parameters. It is not correct to pass the `new_population` to it.
3. This is a critical note. The fitness function you pass to the `fitness_func` parameter calls the `cal_pop_fitness()` method. In PyGAD, the `cal_pop_fitness()` method calls your custom fitness function. Thus, you enter an **infinite loop** where the 2 functions are calling each other.

So, your code cannot work this way.

If you want to get the fitness of the most recent population, you can use the `last_generation_fitness` attribute. Just access it within your fitness function:

```py
ga_instance.last_generation_fitness
```

Note that this attribute is `None` for the first generation. So, you can set it to some initial fitness values before calling the `run()` method:

```py
ga_instance.last_generation_fitness = numpy.array([1, 1])
```